# Oracle SQL: Flatten multiple, priorized, overlapping time-series, and then divide them weekly

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, oracle12c

I'm fairly knowledgeable about basic SQL DDL, but I have no idea if this is possible at all, as I don't even have a grasp of the right terminology to query Google about this.

I've got something like the calculation of hotel room pricing, where someone at beginning of the year inserts the base price for that room category, and then multiple promotional date intervals, for X percent off discounts over the base price, and multiple high-season date intervals, for Y percent raise over the base price. Multiple promotional and high-season intervals shouldn't overlap one another.

After those results are flattened, generating multiple intervals for whole year, then I need to split those in weekly intervals, each one receiving its final price, so that I can materialize and index those dates, for low cost querying, with further calculations.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6cff90/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table room_price_duration
(
 id number,
 hotel_id number,
 room_cat number,
 price_cat number, -- 1 normal  2 promo  3 high season
 start_date date,
 end_date date,
 price number,
 pct number
);

insert into room_price_duration values (1,  1, 1, 1, to_date('20160101','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20161231','YYYYMMDD'), 100, NULL);
insert into room_price_duration values (3,  1, 1, 3, to_date('20160101','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160117','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, +15);
insert into room_price_duration values (2,  1, 1, 2, to_date('20160301','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160430','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, -10);
insert into room_price_duration values (3,  1, 1, 3, to_date('20160701','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160731','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, +10);
insert into room_price_duration values (4,  1, 1, 2, to_date('20160801','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160831','YYYYMMDD'), NULL,  -5);
insert into room_price_duration values (6,  1, 1, 3, to_date('20161121','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20161231','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, +15);

insert into room_price_duration values (7,  1, 2, 1, to_date('20160101','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20161231','YYYYMMDD'), 150, NULL);
insert into room_price_duration values (8,  1, 2, 3, to_date('20160101','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160117','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, +15);
insert into room_price_duration values (9,  1, 2, 2, to_date('20160301','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160430','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, -10);
insert into room_price_duration values (10, 1, 2, 3, to_date('20160701','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160731','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, +10);
insert into room_price_duration values (11, 1, 2, 2, to_date('20160801','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20160831','YYYYMMDD'), NULL,  -5);
insert into room_price_duration values (12, 1, 2, 3, to_date('20161121','YYYYMMDD'), to_date('20161231','YYYYMMDD'), NULL, +15);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from room_price_duration
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6cff90/1/0)**:

```
| ID | HOTEL_ID | ROOM_CAT | PRICE_CAT |                 START_DATE |                   END_DATE |  PRICE |    PCT |
|----|----------|----------|-----------|----------------------------|----------------------------|--------|--------|
|  1 |        1 |        1 |         1 |  January, 01 2016 00:00:00 | December, 31 2016 00:00:00 |    100 | (null) |
|  3 |        1 |        1 |         3 |  January, 01 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 17 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     15 |
|  2 |        1 |        1 |         2 |    March, 01 2016 00:00:00 |    April, 30 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     10 |
|  3 |        1 |        1 |         3 |     July, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     July, 31 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     10 |
|  4 |        1 |        1 |         2 |   August, 01 2016 00:00:00 |   August, 31 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |      5 |
|  6 |        1 |        1 |         3 | November, 21 2016 00:00:00 | December, 31 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     15 |
|  7 |        1 |        2 |         1 |  January, 01 2016 00:00:00 | December, 31 2016 00:00:00 |    150 | (null) |
|  8 |        1 |        2 |         3 |  January, 01 2016 00:00:00 |  January, 17 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     15 |
|  9 |        1 |        2 |         2 |    March, 01 2016 00:00:00 |    April, 30 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     10 |
| 10 |        1 |        2 |         3 |     July, 01 2016 00:00:00 |     July, 31 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     10 |
| 11 |        1 |        2 |         2 |   August, 01 2016 00:00:00 |   August, 31 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |      5 |
| 12 |        1 |        2 |         3 | November, 21 2016 00:00:00 | December, 31 2016 00:00:00 | (null) |     15 |
```

What should I be looking for?

Oracle 12c functions may be used.

Comment: What are your desired outputs? Would it be a table of (hotel_id, room_cat, price_cat, start_date, end_date, final_price) with one record per week per hotel/room_cat/price_cat?